# Error while trying to create thumbnails with php

Tags: php, image-processing

here is my code

```
 $img_dir ="C:\xampp\folders\img\*.jpg";
 $thumb_width = 100;



    // Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents  
 $scan= glob($img_dir);
    foreach($scan as $image) {  


      $im= imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
     $img_width = imagesx($im);
     $img_height=imagesy($im);
    $thumb_height= floor ($img_height *($thumb_width/$img_width));
    $new_img=imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width,$thumb_height);
    imagecopyresized($new_img, $im, 0,0, 0, 0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $img_width, $img_height);
    $thumb_path = "C:\xampp\folders\thumbs\";
    imagejpeg($new_img,$thumb_path);


    }
```

I keep getting this error

```
Warning: imagejpeg(C:\xampp\folders\thumbs): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\folders\index.php on line 32
```

The destination file has read and write permissions! Whats wrong with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of [imagejpeg](http://php.net/imagejpeg) should be the name of a file and not the name of a directory (in your code `$thumb_path` seems to be a directory). Moreover, you should escape the backslashes (write `\\` instead of `\` for a single backslash). Therefore, replace

```
$thumb_path = "C:\xampp\folders\thumbs\";
```

with

```
$thumb_path = "C:\\xampp\\folders\\thumbs\\".basename($image);
```

and I hope your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

there is a permission error, change the permissions of 'thumbs' folder to 775;